# Corodva 5.1.1 AJAX call not working I have the whitelist plugin

Tags: ajax, cordova

I'm trying to update an app to a newer version and I am unable to get my login scripts to work anymore in v 5.1.1 of Cordova.

I have the whitelist plugin installed according to cordova and inappbrowser allows me access to the internet.

I shortened the config.xml to allow all connections. I think

Config.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="org.company.app" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>app</name>
    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-navigation href="*" />
    <allow-intent href="*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>
</widget>
```

Cordova Plugin list.

```
cordova-plugin-console 1.0.1 "Console"
cordova-plugin-file 3.0.0 "File"
cordova-plugin-file-transfer 1.2.1 "File Transfer"
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 1.0.1 "InAppBrowser"
cordova-plugin-media-capture 1.0.1 "Capture"
cordova-plugin-network-information 1.0.1 "Network Information"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.0.0 "Whitelist"
```

Comment: If iOS9 and using xcode then changes to security were made. I had to update 'info.plist' to allow http calls to my api. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/53161545?noredirect=1) is a link to what I am referencing if applicable.

Answer (score 0):

So I moved

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>  


<dict>  
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key><true/>  
  </dict>
```

to the top of my plist file and it started working.  I previously had it at the bottom.  Not totally sure why it worked but it did.